# How to solve Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 console error?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am very confused. My forum was working fine yesterday and today then now I am getting this error and my forum no longer displays or works. I have also got another js and php for posting a new comment. The comment is still being added to my database it is just not appearing. Anyone know why this is? This is the full error I am getting:

```
VM232:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (comments.js:13)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

HTML

```
          <div id="content" class="content">
                <form id="forumPost" method='POST'>
                   <textarea rows="3" col="60" name="comment" placeholder="Create a Post..." id="comment"></textarea>
                   <button><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post' class="post"></button>
                </form>
                <p id="error" class="errormessage"></p>
                <p id="allcomments" class="postmessage"></p>

                <div class="comment-container">
                    <div class="username"><!--obj.username--></div>
                    <div class="comment"><!--obj.comment--></div>
                    <div class="date"><!--obj.commDate--></div>
                    <div class="like"><!--obj.sentiment--></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var comments = document.getElementById("allcomments").value; 

     //Get Storage 
                var username = window.localStorage.getItem("username");

        // Call Ajax for existing comments
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'comments.php',
        success: function(result) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(result);

            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var obj = arr[i];   

                var output = document.getElementById("allcomments");  

                output.innerHTML += '<div class="comment-container"><div class="username">'+obj.username+'</div><div class="comment">'+obj.comment+'</div><div class="date">'+obj.commDate+'</div><div class="like">'+obj.sentiment+'</div></div>';

            }

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

require_once('checklog.php');
require_once("db_connect.php");
require_once("functions.php");

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];

// Print out existing comment
$query  = "SELECT comments.commDate, comments.ID, comments.username, comments.comment, users.username, comments.sentiment FROM comments LEFT JOIN users ON comments.username = users.username"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
if (!$result)
    die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $comments[] = $row; 
//CHECK THAT THE COMMENT USERID MATCHES SESSION USER ID
if ($row['username'] == $username['username']){
$comments .=" <a href='delete_post.php?pID=".$row['ID']."'>Delete</a>";
}
        if(!isset($username["liked_" . $row['ID']])){
                $comments .= "<a href='like.php?likeid=" . $row['ID'] ."'>Like</a>";
        }else{  
                $comments .="Liked"; 
        } 
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

require_once("db_close.php");

echo json_encode($comments);

?>
```

Comment: Check the network tab (in the developer tools) for errors, probably the server is returning 404 error as HTML

Comment: It's possible something in your PHP code is generating extra output (perhaps an error message). If you take a close look in the console at the response you should be able to see what it is and hopefully figure out where it's coming from.

Comment: I'd imagiine it's something to do with comments being an array: `$comments[] = $row;` and then being used as a string: `$comments .=" <a href='delete_post.php?pID=".$row['ID']."'>Delete</a>";`

Comment: Remove the `?>`. No PHP file should have it at EOF. Maybe

Comment: @MarkusZeller my IDE complains if it's not there...

Comment: @Nick That's bad. It needs an update. Having the close tag at the end may result in outputting extra spaces, newlines, etc.

Comment: Yes Nick you were correct! @nick

Comment: @MarkusZeller HTML ignores whitespace so it shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @user13382159 cool - if you've resolved the issue yourself you may as well delete the question.

Comment: If you output a JSON, it does, when a previous include does.

Comment: How would I got about adding a like a comment feature then as that is what I was trying to do there (like and delete comments in the forum) @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this line :

```
$comments[] = $row;
```

You declare `$comments` as array, then :

`$comments .=" <a href='delete_post.php?pID=".$row['ID']."'>Delete</a>";`

you are appending string to array variable which is absolutely wrong

The result you are returning from server is combination on array and string that result's in invalid format so it will not get converted to the js object.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I would go about adding a like a comment feature then as that is what I was trying to do there (like and delete comments in the forum) but it messed up my code

Comment: instead of returning  html tag directly from server add like status in `$comments[]` array i,so you will generate proper json format. Then on client side generate and render html based on that status.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look but I have no idea how to do that haha.